# ArcObjects: How to insert data into a table?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, attribute-table, arccatalog

I have a table in ArcCatalog named WorkOrderAss.

This table contains 3 columns: (OBJECTID, FeatureName, Name).

I want to insert data to this table from the code behind in C#.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this table in SDE, file geodatabase?

Comment: Yes, it is SDE.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public void Irow(ITable table, string nameOfFrstField , string nameofSecField) {

            int fieldFrstIndex = table.FindField(nameOfFrstField);
            int fieldSecIndex = table.FindField(nameofSecField);
            //insert row
            IRow row = table.CreateRow();
            //initalize all of the default field values for the new row.
            IRowSubtypes rowSubTypes = (IRowSubtypes)row;
            rowSubTypes.InitDefaultValues();
            row.set_Value(fieldFrstIndex, "Value1");
            row.set_Value(fieldSecIndex, "Value2");
            row.Store();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

For better performance, consider using [`IRowBuffer`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000007vs000000) and an insert cursor with client-side buffering enabled (e.g. pass in `true` for the `useBuffering` parameter of the [`ITable.Insert`](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000008p2000000) method).

See "Using insert cursors" in the [Creating features](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Creating_features/00010000049v000000/) help topic for more info.